# Recover files inside a folder which was replaced by an empty one. (openSUSE, Ext4)

Tags: opensuse, data-recovery, ext4, replace, deleted-files

Is there a way to restore a folder or better the containing files and folders of the folder which was replaced by a empty one with the same name?

FileSystem: Ext4

OS: openSUSE 42.1

If it is possible, what is the easiest way? 
Can I do this from the running system itself?

Comment: Due to nature of UNIX filesystems, the answer is:not easily and not for sure. But you can find many wanna-be undelete utilities for Linux if you google the right words. Again your mileage may vary and at the end you might not succeed. Just google the phrase "SuSE Linux undelete utility" and you will find myriad of links to such utilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do it from the running system, you should run a live cd or usb, mount the hard drive in read only, then try ext undeleted, or don't mount anything and try foremost or photorec. The more you use the system the less likely it is that you will recover your data. good luck

Comment: I've installed a lot of other stuff after, before I realized the problem. Loosing this data will not kill me. I'll drink a beer, thank you! :-)

Comment: my bad, i forgot, you can also drink a beer.